# hint to find the second derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a non-constant, three times differentiable function. If $f\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=1$ for all integers n, then $f''(1)=$?

by the given condition for n=0 $f(1)=1\\ f'(1)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(1)}{1/n}\text{if taken for integer value of n only}\\ \frac{f(1)-f(1)}{1/n}=0 \\f''(1)=lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f'\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f'(1)}{1/n}=?$ is this correct way to do it, how should I proceed or should end it here :p

Comment: @AnuragA $f$ is continuos

Comment: it's for n=0 in the given condition.

Comment: @Abomm How do you substitute $n=0$?  It should say $f(1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(1+\frac{1}{n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}1=1$ to really use continuity and the condition.

Comment: @Ant I know that but OP says he is using $n=0$. That is why I asked the question.

Comment: @AnuragA Oh, alright then :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sketch: Because $f(1+1/n) = f(1+1/(n+1)),$ there exists $c_n\in (1+1/(n+1),1/n)$ such that $f'(c_n) = 0$ by Rolle's theorem. Apply Rolle again to see there is $d_n\in (c_{n+1},c_n)$ such that $f''(d_n)=0.$ Note the sequence $d_n \to 1.$ Conclude $f''(1)=0$ by the continuity of $f''$ at $1.$

(Note: We did not need $f$ to be thrice differentiable. $f\in C^2$ is enough.)

Comment: thank you for providing the hint but I couldn't figure out myself. But I understand it with the help of candyman explaination.

Answer (score 1):

Write the taylor expansion for $f$ at $1$;

$$f(1+h) = f(1) + h f'(1) + \frac{h^2} 2f''(1) + \frac{h^3}6f^{(3)}(\zeta)$$

for $\zeta \in [0,h]$.

Setting $h = \frac 1n$ and simplifying you get that

$$f''(1) = -2nf'(1) - \frac{1}{6n}f^{(3)}(\zeta) = - \frac{1}{6n}f^{(3)}(\zeta)$$

Because,as you find $f'(1) = 0$. But since $f^{(3)}(\zeta) \to f^{(3)}(1) \in \mathbb R$ as $n \to \infty$ (because $f^{(3)}$ is continuous) you get, taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ that

$$f''(1) = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Set $a_n = 1+\frac{1}{n}$.
Using Rolle's theorem, you know that there are $b_n \in (a_n,a_{n+1})$ such that:

$$f'(b_n) = \frac{f(a_{n+1})-f(a_{n})}{a_{n+1}-a_{n}} = \frac{1 - 1}{\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n}} = 0.$$

Similarly, using Rolle's theorem for second derivative, you get that there are $c_n \in (b_n, b_{n+1})$ such that:

$$f''(c_n) = \frac{f(b_{n+1})-f(b_{n})}{b_{n+1}-b_{n}} = \frac{0 - 0}{\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n}} = 0.$$

If we move $n$ toward infinity, then:

1. $a_n = 1+\frac{1}{n} \to 1$
2. $b_n \to 1$ since $b_n \in (a_n, a_{n+1})$
3. $c_n \to 1$ since $c_n \in (b_n, b_{n+1})$

Thanks to the continuity of $f$, we can conclude that

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} f''(c_n) = f''(1) = 0.$$

Comment: @Ab omm You are welcome. Anyway, I think it's better if you just upvote me and accept the solution of zhw. instead :D

Comment: I accepted your answer so that anyone else who have less knowledge of the context could easily understand it. It is more likely to read the accepted answer first.

Comment: I have a doubt do both $b_n, b_{n+1} \in(a_n,a_{n+1})$ thanks for help

Comment: because I think another such $b_{n+1} \in(a_{n+1},a_{n+2}$ am I right.

Answer (score 0):

It is little known that one can calculate $f^{(n)}(x)$ solely with values of $f$. Let $x_0,\dots x_n$ be mutually different. Then
$$\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}=\lim_{x_0,\dots,x_n\to x}
\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f(x_k)}{(x_k-x_0)\cdots\widehat{(x_k-x_k)}\cdots(x_k-x_n)}\right).$$

Now choose $x_k=1+\frac{1}{m+k}$ to show that every derivative equals zero for $x=1$, provided it exists.