# Using definition of derivative to prove that $\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x_0+bh)-f(x_0-ch)}{(b+c)h}=f'(x_0) $

Tags: derivatives

I'm studying in preparation for a Mathematical Analysis I examination and I'm solving past exam exercises.
*If it's any indicator of difficulty, the exercise is Exercise 4 of 4, part $a$ and graded for 5%, so it's supposed to be pretty easy.*

> Let $b,c>0$, $(b+c\neq 0)$, $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ a space. If $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ derivable at $x_0$ (point inside $I$, prove that $ \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x_0+bh)-f(x_0-ch)}{(b+c)h}=f'(x_0) $

This looks suspiciously like the definition for the derivative, $f'(a)= \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} $

But how can I isolate those $b$s and $c$s out of the equation if I've got no given formula for $f$?

Comment: I wonder why $b+c\ne0$ is demanded if both are $>0$ anyway.

Comment: Add and subtract $f(x_{0})$ in numerator.

Comment: It is a corrolar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637880/hint-to-find-the-second-derivative/1638616#1638616

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Show that $\frac{f(x_0+bh)-f(x_0-ch)}{(b+c)h}$ is between $\frac{f(x_0+bh)-f(x_0)}{bh}$ and $\frac{f(x_0)-f(x_0-ch)}{ch}$. In fact, it is a convex combination ...

> We have
>  $$\frac b{b+c} \frac{f(x_0+bh)-f(x_0)}{bh}+\frac c{b+c}\frac{f(x_0)-f(x_0-ch)}{ch}=\frac{f(x_0+bh)-f(x_0-ch)}{(b+c)h}$$
> and both $bh\to0$ and $-ch\to 0$ as $h\to 0$, hence $\frac{f(x_0+bh)-f(x_0)}{bh}\to f'(x_0)$ and $\frac{f(x_0)-f(x_0-ch)}{ch}=\frac{f(x_0-ch)-f(x_0)}{-ch}\to f'(x_0)$ and so $\frac{f(x_0+bh)-f(x_0-ch)}{(b+c)h} \to f'(x_0)$.

After reading the proof it turns out we do not need $b,c>0$, it suffices to have $b+c\ne 0$ (though we do not have "betweenness" in the general case)

Comment: Thank you for the elegant answer. One question that might be due to me being tired, but how do the two combinations tend to $f'(x_0)$ as $h\to 0$?

Answer (score 0):

By assumption, there is a continuous function $\omega$ such that $f(x)=f(x_0)+\omega(x)(x-x_0)$. Then
$$
f(x_0+bh) = f(x_0)+\omega(x_0+bh)bh, \quad
f(x_0-ch) = f(x_0)-\omega(x_0-ch)ch.
$$
Therefore $$f(x_0+bh) - f(x_0-ch) = \left( b \omega(x_0+bh) + c \omega(x_0-ch) \right)h.$$ This shows that $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+bh) - f(x_0-ch)}{h} = (b+c) \omega(x_0) = (b+c)f'(x_0).$$